# Do scorpions sting themselves to death if they can't escape a threat?

Tags: biology

When scorpions are unable to escape (e.g. surrounded by fire), they apparently will sting randomly and eventually hit themselves, and die.

There are [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-D1LuoJSXQ) that show them stinging themselves and dying, when sprayed with insecticide.

Comment: That could have been death throes from the poison that they sprayed on him. I'm not convinced he actually stung himself. Do you have other video examples?

Comment: I will try to fin some

Comment: @fredsbend ... I have looked as best I can but it seems all the videos of "Scorpion suicide" have them either in alchol or some form of insectiside, one video of of viniger and UV flashlight ... not sure how it makes them attack themself though

Comment: @Mr.Burns The number of videos could be evidence of consistent behavior at least. The question is whether the behavior is intentional or caused by the poison or something else. Certainly at least from the video you did show they believed the Scorpion intentionally stung itself. This could be a better question for biology stack Exchange.

Comment: @fredsbend, I was thinking that, but when I look at the description on the video they ?sprayed? the scorpion with baygon. After looking through more of the videos they all seems to have the scorpion dosed with something ...

Comment: I've edited the question a little, but it still isn't really clear what question you are asking. Q: Do scorpions deliberately kill themselves? Off-topic; a question of motivation, made worse by being about an animal. Q: Can scorpions sting themselves to death? Not notable; no-one is saying they can or can't. Q: Did this particular scorpion that died after being sprayed with a neurotoxin die of its own poison or the neurotoxin? Not notable.

Comment: [Many websites report](https://www.google.nl/search?q=scorpions+sting+themselves+to+death) that this is a fallcy